# How can this be undefined in the constructor of an Angular config class?

Tags: angularjs, constructor, typescript, undefined, this

I've found some examples online, where people create TypeScript config classes and pass them on to Angular. When I've tried it, I got the weird exception, that `this` was undefined. A closer look to the other implementations revealed, they only use the constructor, so, are those examples actually inherently wrong and misleading or did I do anything wrong defining my class?

My code:

```
class TestConfig {
  constructor() {
    console.log('TestThis =>');
    console.log(this);
    console.log('<= TestThis');
  }
}

angular.module('todoList', [])
    .config(TestConfig);
```

This logs for me:

```
TestThis =>
undefined
<= TestThis
```

I wanted to define helper function and use them, to make the configuration in the constructor easier to read. I'm doing it for now with static helper functions, but it is unclear to me why, when it wouldn't work with classes properly, so many people would use it. But I also can't see any problem in my code.

The original code where I got the idea for the config class from, is btw generated by the, otherwise great, [gulp angular generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config functions aren't classes and shouldn't be written as such. Angular is invoking them without `new` and thus `this` will be `undefined` (or, God help you, `window` in non-strict mode).

It doesn't really make sense to use a class here as there's no instance to be kept around. If you want to take advantage of `$inject`, use a function/module pair:

```
function fn($foo) {
}
module fn { export var $inject = ['$foo']; }
```

or just write

```
fn['$inject'] = ['$foo'];
```

Comment: Ok thx for clarification / confirmation. FYI, I've created an [issue on the generators github repo](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/629)

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated a project generated from the previous version of the gulp-angular-generator. I had a few issues, this being one of them.

I simply just exported functions instead of classes. That way I know I can't use `this` in the way I'd expect to with a class.

```
/* @ngInject */
export function Config(
    $logProvider: ng.ILogProvider,
    $httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider,
    $provide: ng.auto.IProvideService,
    RestangularProvider: restangular.IProvider) { 

    /* ... */
}
```

Also notice that I'm using the ngInject attribute. So there's no need to put in `$inject = ['$foo'];` anywhere.

As an aside, I discovered today that references are critical to ensuring the proper order of your typescript files. It worked with the old way of sorting them, but now the generator is doing it slightly different and all my stuff broke because of missing `/// <reference path="..." />` comments.

Make sure you have the following at the top of your index.module.ts file:

`/// <reference path="index.config.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.run.ts" />`